Jolt: dependencies between input array elements
I am trying to transform a JSON document with an array in which the head element controls how the following elements should be treated. If the head element is 'AND', then the following elements are sub-arrays representing predicates:
[
  "AND",
  [
    "=",
    "key1",
    "value1"
  ],
  [
    "=",
    "key2",
    "value1"
  ]
]

Otherwise, the array itself is a single predicate, and the head element is an operator:
[
  "=",
  "key",
  "value"
]

The expected outputs are:
[
  {
    "operator": "=",
    "lhs": "key1",
    "rhs": "value1"
  },
  {
    "operator": "=",
    "lhs": "key2",
    "rhs": "value2"
  }
]

and:
[
  {
    "operator": "=",
    "lhs": "key",
    "rhs": "value"
  }
]

Is this possible with a shift operator, or do I need a custom Transform?

Hi Albert, Can you please individually add input and expected outputs separately with respect to the cases.

Hi Barbaros. Added the output for both cases.

Based on the given criterias and styles of inputs the following transformation will fullfill what you need :
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "0": { //The first element of the array
        "AND": { "@2": "" }, //Keep as the original when first element 
        //of the array is "AND"
        "*": { "@2": "[]" } //Else case : Add an array wrapper 
        //in order to resemble the other case
      }
    }
  },
  { //determine the attributes respectively
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "0": "&1.operator",
        "1": "&1.lhs",
        "2": "&1.rhs"
      }
    }
  },
  { //get rid of the object keys while getting an array of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "[]"
    }
  }
]

